# Watermark gets distorted when 'fit' param set to 'crop' Filepicker

Tags: filepicker.io, filepicker

I am using filepicker service to upload image. when I convert the image and add watermark it gets distorted if 'fit' parameter is set to any other than 'max'. Am I missing somthing?

[Here](https://www.filepicker.io/api/file/hFHUCB3iTxyMzseuWOgG/convert?watermark=http://www.filepicker.io/static/img/watermark.png&watersize=20&waterposition=top,left&w=200&h=200&fit=crop) is an Example and [here](https://developers.filepicker.io/docs/web/#fpurl-images) is Filepicker.io Documentation about Image conversion

Comment: Can you provide a bit more detail on what you mean by distorted? In the example you demonstrated the watermark is getting cropped along with the image

Comment: Exactly! "I Don't want watermarked to be cropped as well" that's what I meant. Is there any way that we can specify the order of conversion? Like first base image is cropped and then watermarked should be applied.

Comment: There is no way to specify the order in a single conversion, but you can do two successive convert() calls to create the desired effect